# what are modern methods to embed inline PDF that are good for UX and index-able and how to fallback in HTML5?

Tags: html, pdf, zurb-foundation, user-experience

I'm trying to incorporate a good user experience (UX) for this Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 page http://iprobesolutions.com/conference-systems/ where I used below HTML5 code to embed the PDF file http://iprobesolutions.com/docs/bosch-dealer-letter.pdf which shows nicely inline in Win XP Chrome but only shows as a link on Win 7 Chrome and Win 7 IE 11.

```
<!-- Embed PDF File -->
<object data="/docs/bosch-dealer-letter.pdf" type="application/x-pdf" title="iProbeDealerLetter" width="700" height="720">
  <a href="/docs/bosch-dealer-letter.pdf">see Bosch dealer letter</a> 
</object>
```

Reading other SO questions about embedding PDFs using `<embed>` vs `<object>` I have not found a definitive solution as a lot of the answers are from several years ago and also this article http://bencreasy.com/object-versus-embed/ while possibly relevant does not really give me a solution for my specific use case.
I'm thinking of either a fallback to a JPEG image of this PDF or if available some other solution that would still keep readable text so search engines can index it but also provide human visitors with better UX.

So my question is two part:

1. What would be the best user experience that still allows for the PDF content to be indexed ?
2. How do I achieve this in code with fall backs or other as I have never done a fallback and don't know what my code should look like and if it's only HTML or if there's JS or CSS I also need to use for fallback in this case.

Comment: I think this depends on the plugins of the browser, rather than the element you use or the type attribute to load it. What if you open the pdf file in your browser manually?

Comment: For a good user experience, the human visitor should not have to worry about plugins and not to have to take action on their end. I'd like to give visitors the possibility of viewing the PDF embedded in a part of the screen like this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uljeb465cnorbp7/Screenshot%202016-06-05%2017.45.34.png?dl=0 Instead, in many browsers it's showing like this with a link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbvp853tch89n8h/Screenshot%202016-06-05%2017.46.45.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the PDF.js library to render it in the page using JavaScript